# How to limit GPU and CPU usage for compatibility testing?

Tags: windows, testing, unity-game-engine, gpu, cpu-usage

I have a Nvidia GTX 1080 and i7 7700k for game development, I can run my games on it smoothly, but I understand that some players have budget builds and wouldn't be able to run my game.

**The question is:** how to limit my PC's computational power so I can simulate player's set up so I can make sure my games run just fine on a budget build?

**One thing to keep in mind:** I can introduce LOW GRAPHICS settings, however, when I run low graphics settings on my machine, it just runs a lot faster, this doesn't solve the problem completely. So the key is to simulate the player's PC's power so I can would be able to know the FPS on a budget graphics card.

It would be handy if the method doesn't require computer reboot, if it has to, I guess that'll do.

Comment: You can underclock the CPU and the GPU, but things like cache, amount of memory etc is harder

Comment: Buy an older graphics card for $50 :) will save you a lot of time compared to trying to find a app to incorrectly artificially limit it which still tells you nothing. What's your time worth to you ?

Comment: Or just use the profiler and see which choke points you have, dont look at the time and look at how much of the total frame time the method takes

Comment: It may be possible, at least for CPU (have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-to-create-a-user-with-limited-ram-usage)). But as Riaan Walters pointed out: A few hours researching are possible more expensive (and maybe unsuccessful) than buying some older secondhand cards.
And I do not think that you can ever be sure that your simulation is correct.

Comment: Quite right, time is money, but micro-stepping performances with easy access may be better. Swapping hardwares in and out causes huge performance steps and installation always needs some tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go To Task manager
2. Select You application in Processes list
3. Select Set Affinity
4. And **Allow processors** accordingly.
5. [image]

This is the way to limit CPU to an application

Comment: But the options are very limited for this kind of performance limitation. And the problem with this approach is, that e.g. a single core at 4GHz with the same microarchitecture as two cores at 2GHz is not the same. Not to mention that you do not restrict the memory controllers with this approach (and the Cache and ...). At last: simulating another microarchitecture is (at least almost) impossible.